# How to get which QradioButton invoke the SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I create several QradioButton and connect to the same SLOT. In the slot, I want to know which QradioButton invoke the slot and do the related action. I found there is a way by using qobject_cast and QObject::sender(), but it seems not work. Here is the code:

header file:

```
class dialoginput : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    dialoginput(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QRadioButton *radio1;
    QRadioButton *radio2;
    QRadioButton *radio3;
private slots:
    void setText_2();
private:
    QLabel *label_0_0;
    QLabel *label_1;
};
```

main file:

```
dialoginput::dialoginput(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent){

    label_0_0 = new QLabel("label_1:");
    label_1 = new QLabel;  

    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *windowLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QGroupBox *box = new QGroupBox("Display Type");
    radio1 = new QRadioButton("3");
    radio2 = new QRadioButton("5");
    radio3 = new QRadioButton("9");
    QVBoxLayout *radioLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    connect(radio1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setText_2()));
    connect(radio2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setText_2()));
    connect(radio3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setText_2()));

    radioLayout->addWidget(radio1);
    radioLayout->addWidget(radio2);
    radioLayout->addWidget(radio3);

    box->setLayout(radioLayout);

    windowLayout->addWidget(box);
    windowLayout->addWidget(label_0_0);
    windowLayout->addWidget(label_1);

    window->setLayout(windowLayout);
    window->show();

}
void dialoginput::setText_2(){

    QObject *object = QObject::sender();
    QRadioButton* pbtn = qobject_cast<QRadioButton*>(object);
    QString name = pbtn->objectName();

    label_1->setText(name);

    if(!QString::compare(name, "3")){       
    }
    else if(!QString::compare(name, "5")){
    }
    else if(!QString::compare(name, "9")){
    }

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    dialoginput *input = new dialoginput();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create separate wrapper slots for each radio button, which then passes the information to the function you want to call. Something like this: -

```
class dialoginput : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QRadioButton *radio1;
    QRadioButton *radio2;
    QRadioButton *radio3;

private slots:
   void Radio1Selected() { setText_2(1); }
   void Radio2Selected() { setText_2(2); }
   void Radio3Selected() { setText_2(3); }

private:
   void setText_2(int id);
```

};

Then connect each radio button: -

```
connect(radio1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Radio1Selected()));
connect(radio2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Radio2Selected()));
connect(radio3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Radio3Selected()));
```

Now when setText_2 is called, the id will represent the selected radio button.

Answer (score 5):

Even though using the `sender()` method solves your problem, i do not recommend using it. The problem is, signals and slots are designed to seperate the emitter and the receiver. A receiver does not need to know which objects, even what types of objects can trigger its slot. When you use `sender()`, you are relying on the fact that the receiver has knowledge of all of the objects that triggers its slot. What if this changes in the future?

You should take a look at `QSignalMapper`, it is designed specifically for this kind of needs. There are good examples about it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting sender Object correctly on setText_2(), But you are not setting objectName property of radio1, radio2 and radio3. Please use "setObjectName( )" API.

Answer (score 0):

write  single argument custom signal for radiobuttons and then emit it .catch that argument in slot.check for corresponding radio button

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a **QButtonGroup** and use lambda expression (c++11)

```
class dialoginput : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

private:
   void setText_2(int id);
   QRadioButton *radio1;
   QRadioButton *radio2;
   QRadioButton *radio3;
   QButtonGroup _btnGroup; 
};
```

After add the 3 QRadioButton to the QButtonGroup

```
_btnGroup.addButton(radio1, 1);
_btnGroup.addButton(radio2, 2);
_btnGroup.addButton(radio3, 3);

connect(&_btnGroup, static_cast<void(QButtonGroup::*)(int)>(&QButtonGroup::buttonClicked), [=](int id){
            setText_2(id);});
```